# QGIS Processing Plugin Generating Features with Attributes

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, qgis-processing, features

I'm writing a QGIS processing plugin that creates a point feature layer. I'm able to add points to the feature layer just fine but the attributes I add don't show up in the Attribute Table after I run the plugin. The Attribute Table shows the correct fields but they're all empty. How do I populate the attribute table from my processing plugin?

Some snippets to give you an idea of what I have now (from my `processAlgorithm` method):

```
field_name = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.FIELD_NAME_INPUT, context)
attrs = ['row', 'col', field_name]
out_fields = QgsFields()
# x and y indexes
out_fields.append(QgsField(name=attrs[0], type=QVariant.Int))
out_fields.append(QgsField(name=attrs[1], type=QVariant.Int))
out_fields.append(QgsField(name=attrs[2], type=QVariant.Double))

(self._sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
       parameters,
       self.OUTPUT,
       context,
       fields=out_fields,
       geometryType=QgsWkbTypes.Point,
       crs=self._bound_box.crs())


attr_vals = np.array([[*coords, randint(1, 5)] for coords in self._defined_points])
# set output field values
for i in range(attr_vals.shape[0]):
    coords = tuple(attr_vals[i, 0:2])
    pin = self._defined_points[coords]
    feat = QgsFeature(id=i
    # this bit works fine
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(*pin.geoCoords()))) 
    self._sink.addFeature(feat)
    # the place where I'm trying to assign the attributes
    feat.setAttributes(list(attr_vals[i, :]))
```

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can produce a MWE. Because we cannot see all the code, it is hard to speculate about what may be the source of the problem, or test any potential solutions.

That said, a blind suggestion: try moving `feat.setAttributes(...)` before `self._sink.addFeature(feat)`. If that doesn't work, try calling `layer.updateFields()` after. Possibly helpful:  https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/

Comment: I think you helped me solve a problem that I created while trying to solve the problem. Moving `feat.setAttributes(...)` to after `self._sink.addFeature(feat)` was one of the things I tried when I was trying to fix the issue by trial and error. However, going back, it does make a difference. When I call `setAttributes(...)` first, the attributes are blank. When I call `addFeature(feat)` first, the attributes are NULL.
`self._sink.updateFields()` gives an error because it's a QgsFeatureSink, not a layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My professor got in touch with a colleague who suggested that the issue was with the datatype.
I changed the assignment code to this, and it solved the problem:

```
attr_vals = np.array([[*coords, QVariant(randint(1, 5))] for coords in self._defined_points])
# set output field values
for i in range(attr_vals.shape[0]):  # if you're concerned, the order here does NOT matter
    coords = tuple(attr_vals[i, 0:2])
    pin = self._defined_points[coords]
    feat = QgsFeature(id=i)
            
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(*pin.geoCoords())))
    feat.setAttributes(list(attr_vals[i, :]))
    self._sink.addFeature(feat)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe corvus is correct, by setting the attributes after you have added the feature you are updating the variable feat not the copy of that which was added to the sink

I would try something like:

```
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(...
feat.setAttributes(...
self._sink.addFeature(feat)
```

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried; moving `feat.setAttributes(...)` to after `self._sink.addFeature(feat)` was one of the things that I tried to make it work.